# Unbounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with finite measure

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have been asked to find an unbounded open set of  $\mathbb{R}^n$  with finite measure. I have thought about using a function such as $e^{-x^2}$ but I don't know very well how to start it.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{q_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be the rational points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (ie each coordinate is a rational). Then the set 
$$
U=\cup_{j=1}^\infty B_{1/j^2}(q_j)
$$
is open, dense, and has finite measure

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider the set
$$
G = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} (2^k, 2^k+2^{-k}),
$$
which has $m(G) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the graph of the function you suggested, from 1 to $\infty$. It's unbounded but it has finite 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure(area).